# Inserting custom key:value pair in JSON structure with custom order using jbuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jbuilder, ruby-2.1

In show method for a controller i have @object setup with query

```
@object = WorkOrder.find(params[:id])
```

Now, the show.json.jbuilder template has code as:

```
json.extract! @object, :id, :note, :status, :created_at
json.store_name @object.store.display_name
```

and the o/p is,

```
{
  "id": 31,
  "note": "work_order for store A",
  "status": "complete",
  "created_at": "2015-11-26T11:16:53.000Z",
  "store_name": "store name"
}
```

Now, how to insert 'store_name' custom key in between 'status' and 'created_at' ?

Comment: try like this =>

json.extract! object, :id, :note, :status,
json.store_name object.store.display_name
json.extract! object, :created_at

Comment: If I may ask, why you do need an order in the json?

Comment: @bo-oz although order doesn't matter, but was eager to know the way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the attributes in a specific order than it would be probably better if you add them by yourself.

**Jbuilder file:**

```
json.id @object.id
json.note @object.note
json.status @object.status
json.display_name @object.store.display_name
json.created_at @object.created_at
```

**Output**

```
{
  "id": 31,
  "note": "work_order for store A",
  "status": "complete",
  "display_name": "store name",
  "created_at": "2015-11-26T11:16:53.000Z"
}
```

I would recommend you to embed relations. It's better scaleable if you want to add other attributes of the `Store`.

**Example:**

**Jbuilder file:**

```
json.id @object.id
json.note @object.note
json.status @object.status

json.store do
  json.name @object.store.display_name
end

json.created_at @object.created_at
```

**Output**

```
{
  "id": 31,
  "note": "work_order for store A",
  "status": "complete",
  "store": {
    "name": "store name"
  },
  "created_at": "2015-11-26T11:16:53.000Z"
}
```

Later you can easily add attributes to the `Store` hash without breaking the interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can also let Rails do the magic like this:

```
render :json => @object, :include => {:store => {:only => :display_name}}
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm afraid it has no way to bring store_name come to other position. YOu should happy with things that you have.